# Java KeyBindings not working after entering text in jTextField?

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings, hotkeys

Basically, I have a java program that acts like a media player, <kbd>PLAY</kbd> <kbd>PAUSE</kbd> <kbd>FAST</kbd> <kbd>FORWARD</kbd> options etc.

Which also have keybindings.

However, in another `JPanel` I also have a `JTextField` that allows the user to enter some text to act as commentary.

If the user decides to write some text, then this `JTextField` is focused and they key bindings don't work anymore.

But if I did `setFocusable(false)` to all containers and child containers, the user won't be able to enter text into the `JTextfield`.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

`JComponent#getInputMap` uses `WHEN_FOCUSED` by default.

Depending on your needs you can use [`WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT) or [`WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW) to change the level of focus you component needs in order to respond to key input

See [`JComponent#getInputMap(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getInputMap-int-) and [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details